# Transform legend when using geom_point and geom_tile for discrete scales (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to plot trends in precipitation from different simulations. I have a data frame, called df, of this kind:

```
    Type season     X       Y     Val
1 25 Ana Annual 76000 2393000  9.724501  
2 25 Ana Annual 76000 2401000 30.416625 
3 25 Ana Annual 84000 2361000  9.724501  
4 25 Ana Annual 84000 2401000  8.234632  
5 25 Ana Annual 84000 2409000 30.416625 
6 25 Ana Annual 84000 2417000 30.416625 
...
```

Type can have four different values: 25 Ana, SST80 T25, 25 CD, Hom

season can have five different values: Annual, Spring, Summer, Autumn, Winter

X and Y are coordinates covering France

Val are Trends

I don't want to plot continuous values so I create classes to have a discrete scale. I create two different scales for season=annual and season=(spring or summer or autumn or winter) because trends don't have the same order of magnitude.

```
coup_a <- c(-127.0405, -110.0000, -100.0000,  -90.0000,  -80.0000,  -70.0000,  -60.0000,  -50.0000,  -40.0000,  -30.0000,  -20.0000,  -10.0000,    0.0000, 10.0000,   20.0000,   30.0000,   40.0000,   50.0000,   60.0000,   70.0000,   80.0000,   90.0000,  100.0000,  110.0000,  127.0405)
lab_a <- c("-110", "-100", "-90",  "-80",  "-70",  "-60",  "-50",  "-40",  "-30",  "-20",  "-10",  "0",    "10",   "20",   "30",   "40",   "50",   "60",  "70", "80", "90",   "100",  "110",  " ")

coup_s <-  c(-72.60114, -40.0000, -35.0000, -30.0000, -25.0000, -20.0000, -15.0000, -10.0000, -5.0000,  0.0000, 5.0000, 10.0000, 15.0000,  20.0000,  25.0000, 30.0000, 35.0000,  40.0000, 72.60114)
lab_s <- c("-40", "-35", "-30", "-25",  "-20", "-15",  "-10", "-5",  "0",  "5",  "10", "15",  "20",  "25", "30", "35", "40",   " ")

pl_a <- df[df$season=="Annual",]
pl_s <- df[df$season=="Spring" | df$season=="Summer" | df$season=="Autumn" | df$season=="Winter",]
```

And now I create the discrete classes thanks to my two scales:

```
pl_a$Val2 <- cut(pl_a$Val, breaks=coup_a, labels =lab_a) 
pl_s$Val2 <- cut(pl_s$Val, breaks=coup_s, labels =lab_s)
```

Interpolation of the colorbrewer colors to have the same number of colors than the classes

```
getPalette <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, "RdYlBu"))
colors_a <- getPalette(length(lab_a))
colors_s <- getPalette(length(lab_s))
```

The plot :

```
p <- ggplot()
p <- (p    
      + theme_bw()
      + facet_grid(saison ~ Type))

p <- (p  + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(1580000,2730000),
                              breaks=seq(1600000,2700000, 200000), 
                              labels= seq(1600,2700,200), expand=c(0,0))
      + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,1250000), 
                           breaks= seq(0,1250000, 400000), 
                           labels= seq(0,1250, 400), expand=c(0,0))
      + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.title=element_blank(), axis.text=element_blank(), legend.key.size=unit(0.5, "cm"), legend.position="bottom")
      + coord_fixed(ratio=1, xlim=c(0, 1100000), ylim=c(1600000, 2730000)))



p1 <- (p
       + scale_fill_manual(name = "Trend", values = setNames(colors_a, lab_a), limits=lab_a, breaks=rev(lab_a), labels=rev(tex_a), na.value="black", guide=guide_legend(label.hjust=-2, label.position="bottom"))
       + geom_tile(data = pl_a[pl_a$Type=="25 Ana" | pl_a$Type=="SST80 T25" | pl_a$Type=="25 CD" | pl_a$Type=="Safran"),], aes(x=X, y=Y, fill= Val2))
       + geom_point(data = pl_a[pl_a$Type=="Hom",], aes(x=X, y=Y, fill= Val2), shape=21, size=2))

p2 <- (p
       + scale_fill_manual(name = "Trend", values = setNames(colors_s, lab_s), limits=lab_s, breaks=rev(lab_s), labels=rev(tex_s), na.value="black", guide=guide_legend(label.hjust=-2, label.position="bottom"))
       + geom_tile(data = pl_s[(pl_s$Type=="25 Ana" | pl_s$Type=="SST80 T25" | pl_s$Type=="25 CD" | pl_s$Type=="Safran"),], aes(x=X, y=Y, fill= Val2))
       + geom_point(data = pl_s[pl_s$Type=="Hom",], aes(x=X, y=Y, fill= Val2), shape=21, size=2))

grid.arrange(p1,p2, heights=c(1, 2.64))
```

tex_s and tex_a are just two vectors like lab_s and lab_a (same length) but with only one value every class like in order to have a readable scale:

```
tex_s <- c("-40", " ", "-30", " ",  "-20", " ",  "-10", " ",  "0",  " ",  "10", " ",  "20",  " ", "30", " ", "40",   " ")
```

And it gives me:

[image]

As you can see, I have a particular case because I only have few points in France for Type=Hom and all France for other types. This is why I need to use both geom_tile with three types and geom_point for type=Hom.

I have three questions:

1) How can I remove the black circles in the legends without removing them in the maps?

2) I use grid.arrange and heights(1,2.64) but in fact I've just tested numbers to have approximately the same size for the annual maps and the other maps but I don't really understand what it represents. If someone can tell me?

3) In order to have a simplified scale, I use "lab" but to have a correct scale, values should be shifted between two classes, like this (values does not match this is just for the example):

[image]

When my legend is placed at the right of the maps (no use of legend.position="bottom") I can shift values using legend.vjust= +/- 1.5 and it works well. But when the legend is below the maps, I try to use legend.hjust but it doesn't work. As you can see, 0 is shifted from two classes and other numbers are still at the same position... How can I do?

Thanks for helping

Comment: When you add you geom_point layer for "Hom" use : `geom_point ( show_guide = FALSE)` to remove the point shape from your legend.